# select ascending or descending according to a parameter

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select -- fields-- 
from myTable 
where -- conditions --
order by myField  if('param'='1' ,'desc','')
```

**if('param'='1' ,'desc','')**: according to that param, I wanna sort ascending or descending.
Executing this query, I get this error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if('param'='1' ,'desc','')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE/WHEN structure:

```
set @param = 1;
SELECT * FROM `myTable`
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @param = 1 THEN myField END ASC,
CASE WHEN @param = 2 THEN myField END DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like?

```
select -- fields-- 
from myTable 
where -- conditions --
order by CASE WHEN @param=1 THEN myField ELSE -myField END;
```

If is generally used inside stored procedures, you have to use CASE/WHEN as show above. Also 'param' doesn't make sense , you probably wanted @param. lastly it's not possible to set ASC/DESC conditionally but the same objective can be achieved by taking the negative/positive of a fields value.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the 2 situation using an `if.. else..` and execute different blocks on different condition.

```
if(@param='1')
select -- fields-- 
from myTable 
where -- conditions --
order by myField desc
else
select -- fields-- 
from myTable 
where -- conditions --
order by myField
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from param and to this:

```
 select -- fields-- 
    from myTable 
    where -- conditions --
    order by if(param ='1') desc
```

And if your param is a int or number for example, also remove the quotes from the value:

```
... if(param =1) desc
```